# Linkedin in company details

Tags: linkedin-api

What is the exact API for getting company details on LinkedIn, such as team size, website, and company profile?
What permission do I need to get?
[https://api.linkedin.com/v2/companies/id](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)
Used this API but didn't get the expected, Only getting 403

```
data: {
      serviceErrorCode: 100,
      message: 'Not enough permissions to access: GET /companies/devtestco',
      status: 403
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/organizations/organization-lookup-api?view=li-lms-2023-01&tabs=http) for LinkedIn's API, you can see clearly that the request should be:

```
GET https://api.linkedin.com/rest/organizations/{organization ID}
```

And the response would include the details you are after.

Comment: The thing is i'm getting 403 error. I need what permission do I need to have it in my app?

Comment: First, you used a wrong endpoint. Second, go over the documentation as it states what permissions you need for this API [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/quick-start?view=li-lms-2023-01).

Comment: I cannot get which product to use for getting company profile details in api. I have a web app where I need users to fill a form for their company, so i need auto fill those details with the api.